# Error when Saving 3d points, which represent a half ellipsoid on Postgis

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

I have a positions of half ellipsoid, these numbers represent coordinates of ellipsoid:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkAtk.png)

But when I try to save this coordinates, it throws an error like:

> Geometry has Z dimension but column does not

I'm a newbie at Postgis, does anybody know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

use *POINT**Z*** instead of *POINT* while creating your table

### long story

It depends on your table definition. Usually you define something like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename (
   geom geometry(geomtype, srid)
)
```

where *geomtype* can be something like *point*, *polygon* or *linestring* and *srid* represents the used coordinate system. Without further informations, these columns will only accept 2d coordinates.

It's possible to store 3d and 4d coordinates, adding *Z* an *M*, as shown in the following example:

```sql
-- allow only 2d points
CREATE TABLE point2d (
    geom geometry(POINT)
);

-- insert 2d point, works
INSERT INTO point2d VALUES ('POINT(10 10)'::geometry);
-- insert 3d point, leads to
-- Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
INSERT INTO point2d VALUES ('POINT(10 10 10)');


-- allow only 3d points
-- by adding Z to POINT
CREATE TABLE point3d (
    geom geometry(POINTZ)
);

-- insert 2d point, leads to
-- Column has Z dimension but geometry does not
INSERT INTO point3d VALUES ('POINT(10 10)'::geometry);
-- insert 3d point, works
INSERT INTO point3d VALUES ('POINT(10 10 10)');
```

It is possible to change the columntype afterwards, but only if the table is empty:

```sql
CREATE TABLE convertme(
    geom geometry(POINT)
);

ALTER TABLE convertme 
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(POINTZ);
```

if there is some data present, you colud do something like this:

```sql
-- delete previous example
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS convertme ; 

-- create new table with 2d geoms
CREATE TABLE convertme(
    geom geometry(POINT)
);

-- insert 2d geom, which prevents changing the 
-- column type
INSERT INTO convertme VALUES ('POINT(10 10)'::geometry);

-- rename the existing column
ALTER TABLE convertme 
RENAME COLUMN geom to geom2d;

-- add 3d column
ALTER TABLE convertme 
ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINTZ);

-- insert existing 2d geometrys
-- by forcing them to be 3d
UPDATE convertme
SET geom = ST_Force3D(geom2d);

-- delete old 2d column
ALTER TABLE convertme 
DROP COLUMN  geom2d;
```